# How are C extensions handled when working with wheels?

Tags: python, pip

I have a package A that depends on package B. Package B has C extensions [sic].

When I do this with package A:

`python setup.py install`

It goes through the install process, compiles the extensions for B if possible (with output noting it), and ignores them if not. So far, as expected.

But if I build a wheel for A and then install that:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
pip install $wheel_file
```

B still gets installed as a dependency, but very quickly; and while the output notes that B's setup.py is being executed, it doesn't say anything else. This leads me to suspect the extensions are not being built or used. I considered that there might be a cache involved somewhere, and tried pip's `--no-cache-dir` option, but it only seemed to force re-downloading dependencies; it didn't add a compilation message or delay.

What exactly is going on here? When do extensions get built, and when not? What gets included in a wheel, and what not?

(Context: I don't particularly care whether I get the extensions in this specific case. The behavior just surprises me, and I want to understand what's going on under the hood)

Comment: It's not clear from your question why `B`'s extensions are compiled if you install `A` - what's going on here? In general, if `B` is installed from wheel file, this wheel file will already contain all C extensions compiled to shared objects (`.so` files). If `B` is installed from source distribution (`.tar.gz`, `.tar.bz2`, `.zip`), then the C extensions are available in source code form and will be compiled to shared object files before installation.

Comment: In the first example, I am installing A using its setup.py; in the second I am installing it from a wheel created with bdist_wheel. In neither example am I explicitly asking for B; it is pulled in as a dependency in whatever the default manner is. My confusion is because the "default handling of the dependency's extensions" appears to differ in each case.

Comment: Ah, I see - then it is indeed different. When `pip install`ing, `pip` will always prefer wheels when available, so the extensions are already compiled and are just copied on installation. `setup.py install`ing will invoke `easy_install` under the hood which doesn't know wheels and will use the source dist, requiring extension compilation on installation. `easy_install` also understands `egg`s as binary distributions, but they are old and rarely used nowadays.

Comment: You can force `pip` into prefering source dists over wheels: try `pip install A --no-binary=B`, you'll notice the increased installation time due to extension compilation on your local machine.

Comment: Okay. Turn that into an answer and I'll probably accept it.